# MySQL FIFO fixed maximum size

Tags: java, mysql, fifo

I need to create a list containing X unique values, each representing a resource. There can be millions of these unique values.

When the application needs a resource it will take the out the value with the lowest id (not value), use the resource and once done with the resource, return the value to the list by adding it to the tail of the list. It is important that the resource is placed at the tail to ensure it will not be used again soon.

To keep the system from losing track of values should the server fail, values in use are added to a simple in_use_value table.

My solution is to create a cyclic FIFO list in MySQL. 
I have a table containing the max number of elements in the list, a header_id field to keep track the front of the list, and a tail_id to keep track of the end. The header and tail id fields are wrapped using modula.

Example:

### values_table

id       INT(10) unsigned
value    VARCHAR(45)

### control_table

max_num_values INT(10)
header_id
tail_id

The problem is that in order to remove or insert a value, I need to lock the control table row to change the tail/header id fields safely. 
Since the application is multi threaded there will be a lot of contention on the control table.

Does anyone have an alternative idea or advice on whether I'm approaching this the correct way? I've thought about partitioning the table into multiple smaller cyclic FIFO lists by splitting the control table into multiple rows mapping to each list, but I don't know how to get a random row from the control table while a row one of the rows are locked.

Any advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. You're approach is good, but you will need to use a concurrent queue so that it plays nicely with the threads.

Comment: I'm using MySQL select for update to get concurrency between threads. Do you thing Java concurrent list would be more efficient?
It is also very important to keep it persistent so that values wont get lost on server failure. That is why I need to keep it in MySQL database.

Comment: @likenoother Yes, select for update is usually something you want to avoid, as that locks the table.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB database to get row level locking. I just don't know whether I can get a unlocked row from the table by doing a random select.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're insistent on persisting it to your database (and ignoring the java side):

You're going about this all wrong.  First off, remember that SQL is, by definition, *un-ordered*.  That means there isn't a 'top' or 'bottom' (indicies make it appear that way, but that's not quite true).

You'll need several tables:

```
Resource  -- List of resource ids - this is how you limit the count.
============
id  -- autoincrement int
allowed  -- boolean flag if this resource is 'present'.  
         -- This is *not* the 'checkout' flag.
natural_key  -- if necessary

Process  -- When a 'thread' spools up, you need to register it.
         -- This is to enable monitor jobs, to clean up/restart dead jobs.
============
id  -- autoincrement int
process_natural_key  -- What the process calls itself.


Checked_out
================
process_id -- fk to Process.id
resource_id  -- fk to Resource.id
checked_out_at -- timestamp, useful for reporting, not otherwise necessary.

Checkin_History
===================
resource_id  -- fk to Resource.id
checked_in_at  -- timestamp, necessary
```

Insert your set of resources into `Resource`.  Set `allowed` as necessary - it's there in case a specific resource is altogether unavailable (say, a server is offline).
Every time a job spools up, have it register itself in `Process`.  This is seperate from any *program-side* registration (like maintaining instances in an `ExecutorPool` or something) - for one thing, it allows you to recover process data, if coded correctly.

You can now 'Check out' your resource by first inserting the record, then querying for the record checked out to your process (or in one go, if your version supports 'DATA CHANGED TABLE REFERENCE's):

```
INSERT INTO Checked_out (process_id, resource_id, checked_out_at) 
SELECT a.id, b.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Process as a
JOIN (SELECT b.id, COALESCE(MAX(d.checked_in_at), 
                      TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01 00:00:00') + b.id SECONDS) as stamp
      FROM Resource as b
      LEFT JOIN Checked_out as c
      ON c.resource_id = b.id
      LEFT JOIN Checkin_History as d
      ON d.resource_id = c.resource_id
      WHERE c.resource_id IS NULL
      AND b.allowed = '1'
      GROUP BY b.id) as b
ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.id, COALESCE(MAX(d.checked_in_at), 
                           TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01 00:00:00') + b.id SECONDS) as stamp
           FROM Resource as b
           LEFT JOIN Checked_out as c
           ON c.resource_id = b.id
           LEFT JOIN Checkin_History as d
           ON d.resource_id = c.resource_id
           WHERE c.resource_id IS NULL
           AND b.allowed = '1'
           GROUP BY b.id) as c
ON c.stamp > b.stamp    
WHERE a.process_natural_key = @programInput
AND c.id IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

This has been tested, and works on a DB2 instance (although not under load).
The statement can also be modified to *not* insert a row if the process already has a check-out row.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I will try implementing it and see what kind of performance I get. I know that the data in MySQL is not ordered from top to bottom, but by using the id value with an index I make it work as an ordered list. I always get the value with the head_id field and add at back by using tail_id+1.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that version is that your header table becomes a bottleneck (because everything needs an exclusive row-lock).  With my version, you almost want to be running under the _least_ lock-level possible.  Although I'd recommend inserting the check-in record, then deleting the check-out record, not the other way around.